# Cannot use PStool for more than 7 PCs over LAN Network

Tags: windows, batch-file

Below is the batch file command I am currently using to shutdown the remote computers through LAN Network.

Here is what it does.

1. I have specified the remote computers IP address in text file named
   **list.txt**
2. I have added an IP as **0.0.0.0** at the bottom of all the remote
   computer IPs.
3. The below batch file will check if the computers are available over
   LAN.
4. If the computer is available it will shutdown the remote PC else it
   will pass on to next IP.
5. When the batch file reads **0.0.0.0** at last it will self shutdown the
   master computer.

My problem is I cannot run this batch for more than 7 remote computers. If I add more than 7 remote PC IP in **list.txt** the batch file hangs and action does not complete. Please let me know if i made any mistake in the code or How i can fix this issue.

I want to run this batch file for minimum of 12 remote PCs

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in (C:\Users\calcopm\Desktop\list.txt) do (
SET IP =%%a
SET C=0
IF %%a equ 0.0.0.0 (
shutdown /s
) ELSE (
ping -n 1 %%a | find "TTL=" >NUL: && SET C=1
IF !C! equ 1 (
psshutdown \\%%a
) else (
ECHO REMOTE %%a IS NOT REACHABLE
)
)
)
```

Comment: It's irrelevant since you don't appear to use the value, but your setting of `IP` is incorrect - spaces are significant on **both** sides of a string-set statement. Try removing the `>nul:` and see what's happening with the `ping`. Does it always stop on the same entry? try shuffling them. What command does it stop at? Try removing the `@echo off` (or change it temporarily to `on`) to see whiere it stops - or loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my script as below and converted from BAT to EXE using an application

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in (C:\Users\calcopm\Desktop\list.txt) do (
IF %%a equ 0.0.0.0 (
shutdown /s
) ELSE (
ping -n 1 -w 100
IF errorlevel 1 (
ECHO REMOTE %%a IS NOT REACHABLE
) else (
psshutdown \\%%a
)
)
)
```

Still I was facing the same problem. As I was running the scripts using exe file(converted using BAT to EXE), I executed using the BAT file it was fine.Then I realised that the BAt to EXE converter had some issues which was affecting the EXE file inturn.

Then I converted BAt to EXE with different application and IT WORKED LIKE A CHARM.

I solved the issue ATLAST!!!!!!!!!!!!! phew!!!!!